# How to find descendant Child from webelement in css

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<div id='test' /><div>
```

In the above example, I need to find div under below scenario:

WebElement

```
divelement = driver.FindElement(By.css("#test"));
```

Now I want to find the div tag with no attribute using the `divelement` variable.

How to navigate to div descendant using `divelement`?

Comment: Could you share relevant HTML as well??

Comment: My scenario is I need to traverse div id using descendant.

Comment: Ok, but without seeing HTML structure we can't help you.thanks

Comment: you can use `divelement.findElement(By.css('div')]"));` or `divelementDescendant = driver.FindElement(By.css("#test  div"));`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways you can do this.

By using a CSS Selector:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#test div"))
//                                      ^  note the space.  this is CSS for "descendant".
```

I'm confused by the phrasing of

> find the div tag with no attribute using the divelement variable.

but if you mean a `<div>` element with no specific attributes, then you can use the `:not()` pseudo-selector.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#test div:not([id])")
// will find all <div>s that are descendants of #test that do not have an id attribute.
```

The other way, is to just use chained `findElement`'s like so:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#test")).findElements("div")
```

Comment: ' ^  note the space.  this is CSS for "descendant". ' is a very good and helpful point.

Answer (score 0):

```
divelement.findElement(By.css("div"));
```

That should be the way to go. That was listed in the comment above from @Sudharsan Selvaraj

Answer (score 0):

If you know the use of double slash `//` in Xpath and looking for its counterpart in CSS, then you need to use space.

For example: You want CSS for grey line then it will be `.image .row.width-for-gray-line`

```
<div class="image parbase wq-GridColumn wq-GridColumn--default--12">
    <div class="component">
        <div class="row bottom-buffer">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <a href="https://msn.com" target="_blank">
                    <picture>
                        <img src="/image/path/cover.jpg"
                            class="image-max-width-responsive" alt="test_alt_text">
                    </picture>
                </a>
                <p class="light-txt">test_caption</p>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row width-for-gray-line">
            <hr class="bottom-buffer-gray-line">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```